# How to create a page to 'Show all product from any category' in Magento?

Tags: magento, filter, categories

On my layout I've a list, like a brand list.

I want to be able to click on the brand to filter my products from ANY categories.

Do I need to create a controller which will handle such behavior ?

Like create a query, remove the category filter and add my custom attribute filter ?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign brands as attribute to your product and assign all products to one category and then you can filter this category by brand or by any other attribute that meets your attribute set.